# Can a recessed IC-rated housing be in contact with nonmetallic sheathed cable?

Tags: wiring, insulation, recessed-lighting, fire-hazard

I have recently installed 8 of these [5 inch insulation contact rated remodler housings](http://www.lowes.com/pd_270969-337-H5RICAT_1z0v1eoZ1z0vgctZ1z0y5pn__?productId=1240111&pl=1&Ntt=halo) in my kitchen.  Two of the holes I made were close to an existing nonmetallic sheathed cable (NM) running through the ceiling, and I believe that the outside of the housing may be in direct contact with the NM cable.

Is this going to be an issue (i.e. do I have to be worried about the NM cable melting and starting a fire), or am I okay because the housing is IC-rated?  In case it matters I plan on using 75 watt halogen bulbs in the housings.

I also placed the housing in contact with the paper facing of the insulation in the ceiling, but I assume this will not be a problem since the housing is IC-rated, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some approved insulations (such as polystyrene) have a lower heat rating than standard NM cable. Since all conventional insulations can touch an IC rated fixture, cable should be no problem.